# How the axiom of subset is applied for proving that $R=\{\langle x,y\rangle \in A\times B: \phi (x,y)\}$ is a set?

Tags: set-theory

The following argument is taken from *Daniel W. Cunningham. “Set Theory: A First Course.”*:

> Given a formula $\phi(x, y)$ and sets $A$ and $B$, the subset axiom implies that one can construct a relation $R$ by forming the set: $R=\{\langle x,y\rangle \in A\times B: \phi (x,y)\}$.

However, I can't see how the axiom of subset is being applied here because my understanding is that $\phi (x, y)$ is not the same as $\phi(\langle x, y\rangle)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set builder notation can sometimes be a bit confusing. Its most simple form is $A=\{x│ϕ(x)\}$. Here $y∈A⟺ϕ(y)$. A more complex form is  $B=\{ψ(x)│ϕ(x)\}$ and here $y∈B⟺ϕ(y)∧ψ(y)$. So we can restate $R$ as $R= <z|z= <x,y> ∧ (z∈A$ x $B ∧ \phi (x,y))>$.  And so $(z∈R) ⟺(z= <x,y> ∧(z∈A$ x $B ∧\phi(x,y))>)$.

Using the axiom of subset, we know $∃B(∀z(z∈B↔(z∈C) ∧ \psi (z))$ for some known set $C$ and fol equation $\psi (z)$. So, just take $C= A$ x $B$ and $\psi(z)≡(z=<x,y> ∧ \phi(x,y))$. Then we know $∃B(∀z(z∈B↔(z∈A$ x $B ∧ z= <x,y> ∧ \phi(x,y))$.  Or in other words, $R$ is a set.

Comment: Isn't that the same as defining this formula: $\psi(\langle x, y\rangle)=(\exists x\in A)(\exists y\in B)(\langle x, y \rangle=\{\{x\},\{x, y\}\})\phi(x,y)$, which appears in the second comment for Lee Mosher's answer?

Comment: To apply the subset axiom, we need a known set and a FOL formula with one free variable (as per the standard formulation of this axiom). What are you proposing for each?

Comment: known set is $A\times B$ and the formula is $\psi(\langle x, y\rangle)$ defined as above based on $\phi(x, y)$.

Comment: Well you don't need to mention $A$ and $B$ in your FOL formula. You just need $\psi(<x,y>)≡\phi(x,y)$ or if you want to make $\psi$ a formula with one free variable to fit in with the axiom schema, $\psi(z)≡(z=<x,y>∧\phi(x,y))$

Answer (score 3):

You're right that they aren't the same.

So your proof will need an extra step, starting by defining a new formula
$$\psi\bigl(\langle x,y \rangle\bigr)=\phi(x,y)
$$

Comment: But how exactly to define a general formula for $\psi$ in all cases of $\phi$ is what I'm struggling with. Even in specific cases like, $\phi(x,y)= (x \in y)$ or $\phi(x, y)= (x = y)$, I couldn't figure out a way to write those formulas in form of $\psi(\langle x, y\rangle)$. For the second case, $\psi(\langle x,y \rangle) = (\langle x,y \rangle= \langle y,x \rangle)$ seems promising but it has $\langle y, x \rangle$ also which I'm not sure whether it's a new variable or something else.

Comment: After some thought, I came up with this way of defining $\psi$: $\psi(\langle x, y\rangle)=(\exists x \in A)(\exists y \in B)(\langle x, y\rangle)=\{\{x\}, \{x, y\}\})\phi(x, y)$. Is that correct or there's a shorter way of defining it?